# How to redirect from one Razor Page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an Page called Page1.

Inside of `OnGet(string parameter1)`  I check a parameter, and in some case want to route the user to another Page.

The Page is located here:

Pages/App/App.cshtml

I have tried this:

```
 this.RedirectToPage("/App/App");//
```

But the user does not get redirected.  It just shows the same page as expected if the redirect was not there.  I want them to see the App page.

So how do I redirect to the App page?

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string web_registration_key)
{
  //Check parameter here

    if(doRedirect)
    {
       return RedirectToPage("/App/App")
    }

  }

  return null;

}
```

The return null seems odd, but not sure what else to return.

Answer (score 2):

I used the return Page();

Here is an example from on of my projects:

```
    public IActionResult OnGet(int id)
    {
        var MenuItemFromDb = _db.MenuItem.Include(m => m.CategoryType).Include(m => m.FoodType)
                .Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (MenuItemFromDb == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ShowCart(id);
            return Page();
        }
    }

    private void ShowCart(int id)
    {
        var MenuItemFromDb = _db.MenuItem.Include(m => m.CategoryType).Include(m => m.FoodType)
            .Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        CartObj = new ShoppingCart()
        {
            MenuItemId = MenuItemFromDb.Id,
            MenuItem = MenuItemFromDb
        };
    }
```